# How do compile and run a Objective-C project in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compilation

I followed [Objective-C beginner's guide](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html) and created a few files. Then I created an Empty Project in XCode and imported the files. Now I want to compile and run them from XCode. How can I do that? The Run/Debug menu option in XCode doesn't seem to be available.

What template should I use in XCode to write a "Hello World" application in Objective-C not using Cocoa? I can't find any appropriate template. The Empty Project doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: There are extensive guides available via the Help menu

Comment: @trojanfoe: I only find guides using Cocoa, not only Objective-C.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Where in the documentation can I find instructions for running a simple Hello World coded in Objective-C using XCode?

Comment: @Jonas: Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DocViewerHomePage/

Comment: @Jonas: The guide you linked uses the Cocoa Foundation framework. You're drawing a distinction that isn't there.

Comment: @Chuck: Ah, I just wanted to run the examples in that tutorial using XCode, which doesn't seem to be that easy using the "Cocoa Application" template in XCode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What template should I use in XCode to write a "Hello World" application in Objective-C not using Cocoa?

You should create a command line tool with the Foundation framework as follows:
[image]

I realize that you don't want to use Cocoa, and I realize that Foundation is the "framework that contains the non-GUI Cocoa classes." ([*Learning Objective-C 2.0*](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321711386)) However, this is the recommended method for creating a non-GUI Objective-C application by all of the following:

- [*Learn Objective-C on the Mac*](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430218150) by Mark Dalrymple and Scott Knaster. As stated on p. 9, "All the programs in this book are based on the Foundation framework."
- [*Learning Objective-C 2.0*](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321711386) by Robert Clair.
- [*Learn C on the Mac*](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430218096) by Dave Mark. On p. 320 in Chapter 12: Where Do You Go from Here, Dave Mark states that the command line tool with the Foundation framework "is the starting point for your next big adventure—mastering Objective-C."

Answer (score 4):

> What template should I use in XCode to write a "Hello World" application in Objective-C not using Cocoa?

You probably want a foundation command line tool.

In Xcode (assuming 3.2.x) select `File/New Project...`

In the window that appears, on the left hand side, select Mac OS X application.  The top right hand pane should display four options

- Cocoa application
- Cocoa Applescript application
- Quartz composer application
- Command line tool.

It's the last option you want.

Having selected command line tool, a drp down list should appear below the pane, from which you should select `foundation`.

That will give you a hello world application which is ready to be compiled and run.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new empty project you should use one of the standard project templates, then add your files to that.

Comment: What project type should I use? I'm not using Cocoa, and on the command line project only C is available as language, not Objective-C. Can't I follow this tutorial using XCode?

Comment: @Jonas: The "Foundation Tool" project type is an Objective-C command-line tool.